# Кондовый - происхождение слова

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Недавно попалось мне в тексте слово "кондовый". Собственно, оно и раньше попадалось, и по контексту был более-менее понятен смысл. Но хотелось бы узнать все-таки точное значение этого слова и, главное, очень интересно происхождение его.
Как я понимаю, это просторечное выражение или сленг. Так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не надо Даля. )))
**Кондовое (дерево)** - пригодное для изготовления кондовой древесины - высококачественной, прочной, поддающейся обработке, идущей на дорогие столярные изделия. В первую очередь характеризуется отсутствием сучков.

Это достаточно известный профессиональный термин. Тут интереснее другое, как слово в разговорно-сниженной речи приобрело едва ли не противоположный оттенок (близкий к "грубому, неотесанному").  Что-то мне подсказывает, что возможно существовало какое-то омонимичное или близкое слово, в результате смешения с которым и появилось современное "кондовый". (уж не "кондом" ли? :))
(+)
Вот нашел (в неавторитетном источнике но очень близкое моему пониманию):

> Кондовый: традиционный, прочный, крепкий, исконный; также в смысле грубоватый, старомодный, неотесанный, жесткий.

Даже трудно представить, по какой линии тут могла идти трансформация значения. Разве что по "прочности".

Comment: У А.Блока в поэме "Двенадцать": "Товарищ, винтовку держи, не трусь! /Пальнем-ка пулей в святую Русь - / В к о н д о в у ю / В избяную / В толстозадую!" Здесь, по смыслу, В КОНДОВУЮ употреблено в значении соответственно тем, которые привёл @behemothus.

Comment: Тут спорно.  
Но в принципе оно сейчас так и употребляется. Вопреки исходному значению. Потому и вопрос возник.

Answer (score 3):

В русско-английском словаре ненормативной лексики приводится только наречие "кондово" с пометкой просторечие (но не жаргон), например: "Охранница так кондово облапила мое удостоверение, что я затревожился: вернет ли?"

Значение: грубо, прочно, крепко, накрепко; roughly, firmly, fast.

Еще примеры

Прямое значение: Бор― дремучий, кондовый, с берлогами медвежьими.  Да еще лес-то какой идет на барку ― самый кондовый, первый сорт!

Переносное значение: деревенский кондовый быт, кондовый стиль и прямолинейность оценок, мое косноязычие и кондовый английский, кондовый армейский афоризм. Живут русские люди, бородачи, кондовый народ, рыбу ловят, сено косят. Ведь он же кондовый гуманист. - А я подумал, что слово «кондовый» в приложении к чему-либо другому звучит, возможно, не так уж приятно, но в сочетании со словом гуманизм оно, на мой взгляд, прекрасно.

Развитие значения: прочный, крепкий, жесткий, тяжелый - неповоротливый, грубый, прямолинейный, примитивный.

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря Даля:

> > Конда
> > жен., архан. конга вологод., пермяц. боровая (не болотная) сосна, крепкая, мелкослойная и смолистая, растущая на сухом месте; древесина ее бывает красновата, и дерево также называют рудовым.
> > | В вологод. иногда и сухой на корню, подстойный хвойный лес (см. мянда).
> > | Чистая, плотная и частослойная часть хвойного дерева, от сердцевины до блони. Кондовый архан., вологод., вят., сиб. **о лесе: крепкий, плотный и здоровый**, не трухлявый; о сосне: боровой, рудовый; вообще: дошлый, превосходный, первой руки. Кондовье, конговье ср., собир. кондовый бор; рудовый лес; ·противоп. мяндяк, мендовый, кондовый, частослойный, с малою болонью; мендовый, рыхлый, редкослойный, блонастый, и потому этот скорее трухлявость.

В толковом словаре Ожегова есть пометка "спец."

Answer (score 0):

Кондега, бывшая сплавная (молевой сплав) речка в лодейнопольском районе Ленобласти.
Конда- приток Иртыша.
А почему не связать  это с латынью, простенько и незамысловато от кондиционного леса, пригодного для строительства?

Answer (score 0):

Кондовый стиль – это грамотно построенный текст, в соответствии с правилами синтаксиса,. Возможности у него большие, для выразительного и образного повествования. Когда судят, что этот стиль тяжеловесный, неповоротливый, надо говорить не об этом, а  о не владении стилем, или неграмотным лексическим и синтаксическим  построением текста.
Тут никто не говорит о пластике языка. А если стиль кондовый, то он и пластичный, не рассыпается при редактировании или не подаётся редактированию. Хотя иной редактор способен искажать, упрощать. У них цель: выхолащивать даже грамотный текст, поскольку такая установка у иных издательств, которые выпускают книги, лексически обеднённые и до невероятности упрощённые, так как это требование рынка, который не заботиться о лексически насыщенном языке.
Хотя в русском языке и литературе термин «кондовый» не употребляется. Скорее всего, он не связан с наукой. А если в обиходе, надо говорить – кондовый стиль, значит экспрессивный, насыщенный стилистическими фигурами и тропами.
Так что хорошо это или плохо – кондовый стиль – решать каждому. Считаю – это вульгарное определение. Настоящая литература его не признаёт, она решает свои эстетические задачи. На тему русского языка можно рассуждать долго.

Comment: Простите, но это Ваши личные размышления на данную тему? Если нет, то не могли ли бы Вы привести ссылку на источники такого трактования?

Comment: Присоединяюсь. Хотелось бы видеть хоть какие-то ссылки. А заодно и ответ на собственно вопрос, что это за слово такое, каково его происхождение. Ваше эссе совершенно не раскрывает сути вопроса.